# Search through folder of workbooks for greater than value

Tags: excel, vba, filesystemobject

I need VBA code that allows me to search multiple workbooks for a value greater than 20 in a specified cell range and summarize the findings back to me. The range I need searched starts at G15 and ends when the string "R2" is reached in column G.

I found code that does something similar, shown below. I need to adjust this code to search for float values less than 20 instead of a string and only search within the range (G15 to when G ="R2').

```
Sub SearchFolders()
'UpdatebyKutoolsforExcel20151202
    Dim xFso As Object
    Dim xFld As Object
    Dim xStrSearch As String
    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xStrFile As String
    Dim xOut As Worksheet
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xWk As Worksheet
    Dim xRow As Long
    Dim xFound As Range
    Dim xStrAddress As String
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xUpdate As Boolean
    Dim xCount As Long
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    xFileDialog.Title = "Select a forlder"
    If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
    xStrSearch = "CV"
    xUpdate = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xOut = Worksheets.Add
    xRow = 1
    With xOut
        .Cells(xRow, 1) = "Workbook"
        .Cells(xRow, 2) = "Worksheet"
        .Cells(xRow, 3) = "Cell"
        .Cells(xRow, 4) = "Text in Cell"
        Set xFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set xFld = xFso.GetFolder(xStrPath)
        xStrFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\*.xls*")
        Do While xStrFile <> ""
            Set xWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=xStrPath & "\" & xStrFile, UpdateLinks:=0, ReadOnly:=True, AddToMRU:=False)
            For Each xWk In xWb.Worksheets
                Set xFound = xWk.UsedRange.Find(xStrSearch)
                If Not xFound Is Nothing Then
                    xStrAddress = xFound.Address
                End If
                Do
                    If xFound Is Nothing Then
                        Exit Do
                    Else
                        xCount = xCount + 1
                        xRow = xRow + 1
                        .Cells(xRow, 1) = xWb.Name
                        .Cells(xRow, 2) = xWk.Name
                        .Cells(xRow, 3) = xFound.Address
                        .Cells(xRow, 4) = xFound.Value
                    End If
                    Set xFound = xWk.Cells.FindNext(After:=xFound)
                Loop While xStrAddress <> xFound.Address
            Next
            xWb.Close (False)
            xStrFile = Dir
        Loop
        .Columns("A:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
    MsgBox xCount & "cells have been found", , "Kutools for Excel"
ExitHandler:
    Set xOut = Nothing
    Set xWk = Nothing
    Set xWb = Nothing
    Set xFld = Nothing
    Set xFso = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = xUpdate
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

Any tips or suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Are all the cells in the range (G15 to when G ="R2') numeric or are there any blank/text cells also ?

Comment: There will be blank cells and also cells containing text.

Answer (score 0):

try

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SearchFolders()

    Const LIMIT = 20
    Const SEARCH_TEXT = "R2"
    Const SEARCH_COL = "G"
    Const START_ROW = 15 ' start row

    Dim oFso As Object, oFld As Object
    Dim oFileDialog As FileDialog
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wsOut As Worksheet
    Dim rngSearch As Range, rngFound As Range, cell As Range
    
    Dim strPath As String, strFile As String, strAddress As String
    Dim iRow As Long, iCount As Long, iLastRow As Long, t0 As Single
    t0 = Timer
    
    Set oFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    oFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    oFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder"
    If oFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        strPath = oFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    If strPath = "" Then Exit Sub
    
    Set wsOut = Worksheets.Add
    iRow = 1
    
    With wsOut
        .Cells(iRow, 1) = "Workbook"
        .Cells(iRow, 2) = "Worksheet"
        .Cells(iRow, 3) = "Cell"
        .Cells(iRow, 4) = "Text in Cell"
        Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set oFld = oFso.GetFolder(strPath)
        strFile = Dir(strPath & "\*.xls*")
        Do While strFile <> ""
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strPath & "\" & strFile, UpdateLinks:=0, ReadOnly:=True, AddToMRU:=False)
            For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
            
                ' determine last row in column
                iLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, SEARCH_COL).End(xlUp).Row
                
                ' check after start
                If iLastRow <= START_ROW Then
                   Debug.Print "Empty col " & SEARCH_COL, wb.Name, ws.Name
                Else
                
                    Set rngSearch = ws.Range(SEARCH_COL & START_ROW & ":" & SEARCH_COL & iLastRow)
                    Debug.Print "Searching", wb.Name, ws.Name, rngSearch.Address
                    
                    Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(SEARCH_TEXT)
                    If rngFound Is Nothing Then
                      ' do nothing
                      Debug.Print SEARCH_TEXT & " Not found", wb.Name, ws.Name, rngSearch.Address
                    Else
                       Set rngSearch = ws.Range(SEARCH_COL & START_ROW & ":" & SEARCH_COL & rngFound.Row - 1)
                       Debug.Print "Scanning", wb.Name, ws.Name, rngSearch.Address
                       
                       For Each cell In rngSearch
                          If Not IsNumeric(cell.Value) Or IsEmpty(cell) Then
                           ' text or blank do nothing
                          ElseIf cell.Value < LIMIT Then
                            iRow = iRow + 1
                            iCount = iCount + 1
                            .Cells(iRow, 1) = wb.Name
                            .Cells(iRow, 2) = ws.Name
                            .Cells(iRow, 3) = cell.Address
                            .Cells(iRow, 4) = cell.Value
                          End If
                       Next
                    End If
                
                End If
            Next
            wb.Close (False)
            strFile = Dir
        Loop
        .Columns("A:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
    MsgBox iCount & " cells have been found - see " & wsOut.Name, vbInformation, "Completed in " & Int(Timer - t0) & " secs"
    wsOut.Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```